# Writing a select query?

Tags: group-by, oracle10g, inner-join

I have two tables:

```
  table1 =tbl_main:

  item_id fastec_qty   sourse_qty
   001       102         100
   002       200         230
   003       300         280
   004       400         500

  table2= tbl_dOrder
    order_id    item_id     amount
     1001          001      30
     1001          002      40
     1002          001      50
     1002          003      70
```

How can I write a query so that the result of the tables are as follows:

```
  sum(fastec_qty)       sum(sourse_qty)   difference1  sum(amount)   difference2  
       1002                1110              -108         190           812
```

difference1 =sum(fastec_qty)-sum(sourse_qty);

difference2 =sum(fastec_qty)-sum(amount);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select sum(m.fastec_qty)
     , sum(m.sourse_qty)
     , sum(m.fastec_qty) - sum(m.sourse_qty)
     , sum(o.amount)
     , sum(m.fastec_qty) - sum(o.amount) 
  from tbl_main m
     , tbl_dOrder o 
 where m.item_id = o.item_id 
 group by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Comment: item_id=004 Not linked to any record in the second table, however I want to account

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a hint, start by joining the tables on the item_id.

```
select item_id.tbl_main fastec_qty.tbl_main 
     , source_qty.tbl_main
     , order_id.tbl_order
     , amount.tbl_order 
  from tbl_main
     , tbl_order 
 where item_id.tbl_main = item_id.tbl_order;
```

next step is to sum the three columns and finally do the subtraction.

Comment: item_id=004 Not linked to any record in the second table, however I want to account

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT sum(a.sourse_qty) as samount,  sum(a.fastec_qty) AS amount,
        sum(a.sourse_qty- a.fastec_qty) as sfd,
        (select sum(ITEM_QTY) from TBL_DO )as  qty,
         sum(a.fastec_qty) - (select sum(ITEM_QTY) from TBL_DO ) AS difference
        FROM   tbl_main  a group by 1,2,3,4,5

  amount       samount    sfd          qty       difference

   1002         1110     -108          190           812
```

Thanks All ,